# X11 forwarding over SSH does not render GUI correctly on MacOS

Tags: ssh, rhel, x11, osx

Wondering if anyone has run into problems with X11 forwarding over SSH does not render GUI correctly on MacOS?   I only see partial screen:

[image]

I have MacOS high sierra 10.13.3 and latest XQuartz 2.7.11 package installed. Server side is Redhat Linux:

LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
Release:    6.9
Codename:   Santiago

I use "ssh -X uid.remote RHEL IP".

Any ideas?